# Is it true that any set in R can be formed by a disjoint and countable union of Borel sets?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given the definitions of independence in Durrett's book of probability theory:

> Two random variables $X,Y$ are independent if $\forall A, B \in R$, $P(X^{-1}(A), Y^{-1}(B))=P(X^{-1}(A))P( Y^{-1}(B))$
>   Two $\sigma$-field $F,G$ are independent if $\forall A \in F$ and $\forall B \in G$, $P(A, B)=P(A)P(B)$

Prove if $X \in F$, $Y \in G$ and $F$ and $G$ are independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

My argument goes as follows:

> $\forall A,B \in R$, there exists countable disjoint Borel sets $\left\{\alpha_n \right\}$ and $\left\{\beta_n \right\}$ s.t $A=\bigcup\alpha_n$ and $C=\bigcup\beta_n$.
>   Then 
>   \begin{align}
> P(X^{-1}(A),Y^{-1}(B))&=P(X^{-1}(\bigcup \alpha_i),Y^{-1}(\bigcup \beta_j)) \\&=\sum_i\sum_jP(X^{-1}(\alpha_i),Y^{-1}(\beta_j)) \\  &=\sum_i\sum_jP(X^{-1}(\alpha_i))P(Y^{-1}(\beta_j)) \\ &=\sum_iP(X^{-1}(\alpha_i)).\sum_jP(Y^{-1}(\beta_j))\\ &=P(X^{-1}(A))P(Y^{-1}(B))
> \end{align}

But I'm not sure the claim of the existence is correct.

A second thought, should $A,B$ in the definition of independence of random variables $X,Y$ be Borel sets? Otherwise, we may not have $X^{-1}(A),Y^{-1}(B)$ be measurable.

Comment: And please replace "Two random variables $X,Y$ are independent if $\forall A, B \in R$..." by "Two random variables $X,Y$ are independent if $\forall A, B \in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$..."

Comment: Does that mean $A$ and $B$ must be Borel sets?

Comment: You are right. Just realised that Durrett uses italic $R$ to denote the Borel sets. Misunderstood the content.  Thanks

Comment: @Did the Cantor set is Borel itself being a compact set.  Nevertheless the statement in the title is false: since the Borel sets are a $\sigma $-algebra they are closed under countable union, therefore it suffice to take a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R $, which exists because Borel sets have the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @Del Yes, my first comment was slightly too hasty.

Comment: @Del Why does the collection of Borel sets have the cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: @LeiHao Yes: the set of Borel sets has the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: It is usually proven by transfinite induction, I'm sure you can find something related here on math.stackexchange. Anyway here we need much less, namely just *one* non-Borel set, which for example is given by the Vitali set